# JQuery load function different results to URL

Tags: php, jquery, load

The following function triggers a search function and loads their results into a container. For some unknown reason, unlike if one types the URL and query into the browser bar, it only seams to work if their are 5 or more characters in the search.????

```
function searchelectors(q){
    t=$(q).val().replace(" ","+");
    $('.searchelectors').load('<?php echo 'http://'.$site_url.$site_uri;?>?q=' + t + ' .searchelectors',function(){
        $('.searchelectors .wheel').slideUp(200);   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encode your querystring value and send it. You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) method.

```
function searchelectors(q){
    t=$(q).val().replace(" ","+");
    t = encodeURIComponent(t);
    $('.searchelectors').load('<?php echo 'http://'.$site_url.$site_uri;?>?q=' + t + ' .searchelectors',function(){
        $('.searchelectors .wheel').slideUp(200);   
    });
}
```